# Jquery loops with changing class search

Tags: jquery

Does anyone know how to put this in a loop?

It's basicly 7 times the same jquery code but the only thing that changes is the row number.

I've tried fixing it like you would write php code but it only gives me errors.

```
$('.row1').mouseenter(function(e){
    $('.row1').addClass('deepskyblue');
}).mouseleave(function(e){
    $('.row1').removeClass('deepskyblue');
}).on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});

$('.row2').mouseenter(function(e){
    $('.row2').addClass('deepskyblue');
}).mouseleave(function(e){
    $('.row2').removeClass('deepskyblue');
}).on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    clickedRow = e.currentTarget.className;
});

$('.row3').mouseenter(function(e){
    $('.row3').addClass('deepskyblue');
}).mouseleave(function(e){
    $('.row3').removeClass('deepskyblue');
}).on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    clickedRow = e.currentTarget.className;
});

$('.row4').mouseenter(function(e){
    $('.row4').addClass('deepskyblue');
}).mouseleave(function(e){
    $('.row4').removeClass('deepskyblue');
}).on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    clickedRow = e.currentTarget.className;
});

$('.row5').mouseenter(function(e){
    $('.row5').addClass('deepskyblue');
}).mouseleave(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.row5').removeClass('deepskyblue');
}).on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    clickedRow = e.currentTarget.className;
});

$('.row6').mouseenter(function(e){
    $('.row6').addClass('deepskyblue');
}).mouseleave(function(e){
    $('.row6').removeClass('deepskyblue');
}).on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    clickedRow = e.currentTarget.className;
});

$('.row7').mouseenter(function(e){
    $('.row7').addClass('deepskyblue');
}).mouseleave(function(e){
    $('.row7').removeClass('deepskyblue');
}).on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    clickedRow = e.currentTarget.className;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could [use multiple selectors.](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

[Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0ejd00j0/)

```js
$('.row1,.row2,.row3,.row4,.row5,.row6,.row7').mouseenter(function(e){
    $(this).addClass('deepskyblue');
}).mouseleave(function(e){
    $(this).removeClass('deepskyblue');
}).on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    clickedRow = e.currentTarget.className;
});
```

```css
div
{
  padding: 5px;
  background-color:red;
  width:100px;
  height: 20px;
}

.deepskyblue
{
  background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='row1'></div>
<div class='row2'></div>
<div class='row3'></div>
<div class='row4'></div>
<div class='row5'></div>
<div class='row6'></div>
<div class='row7'></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a for loop

```
for ( var i = 1; i < 8; i++ ) {
   $( '.row' + i ).mouseenter(function(e){
      $( '.row' + i ).addClass('deepskyblue');
   }).mouseleave(function(e){
      $( '.row' + i ).removeClass('deepskyblue');
   }).on('click',function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      clickedRow = e.currentTarget.className;
   });

}
```

Comment: I'll test it when I get home but I used "." instead of "+" so I'll this this will work... Beginner mistakes :/

Comment: @Wanjia That kind of mistake isn't just for beginners. I still do it once in a while when switching between PHP and Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the HTML page add the same class for each item that requires the same behavior. i.e  `class="row-highlight"`  You can then use `$('.row-highlight')` to get all of the DOM elements in a single call

Like replace all `row*` class with `row-highlight` and do below

```
$('.row-highlight').mouseenter(function(e){
    $('.row-highlight').addClass('deepskyblue');
}).mouseleave(function(e){
    $('.row-highlight').removeClass('deepskyblue');
}).on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```